# How to override @CreatedBY value from AbstractAuditingEntity in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

We have a microweb service environment in which AbstractAuditingEntity coming from another common micro service. And I want to override @CreatedBy property of this abstract class with my own defined value.

My code is given below.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity {

@Column(name = "created_by", insertable = true, updatable = false,     nullable = false)
@CreatedBy
private String createdBy;

@Column(name = "created_date", insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@CreatedDate
private DateTime createdDate;

@Column(name = "last_modified_by", nullable = false)
@LastModifiedBy
private String lastModifiedBy;

@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@LastModifiedDate
private DateTime lastModifiedDate;

// @Transient
public abstract Long getInternalId();

// @Transient
public abstract void setInternalId(Long internalId);

public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(DateTime createdDate) {
this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public DateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
return lastModifiedDate;
}

public void setLastModifiedDate(DateTime lastModifiedDate) {
this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
}

public String getCreatedBy() {
return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

public String getLastModifiedBy() {
return lastModifiedBy;
}

public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
}
}
```

And my Domain class is like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "programs")
 @AttributeOverride(name = "createdBy", column = @Column(name = "created_by"))
public class Program extends AbstractAuditingEntity {

 @Id
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "programs_seq", sequenceName = "programs_seq")
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "programs_seq")
 @Column(name = "internal_id", nullable = false)
 private Long internalId;

 private String programName;  

 @Override
 public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this,    ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);
 }
//Start getters & setters - auto generated by IDE

 @Override
 public Long getInternalId() {
   return internalId;
 }

 @Override
  public void setInternalId(Long internalId) {
    this.internalId = internalId;
  }

  public String getProgramName() {
    return programName;
  }

  public void setProgramName(String programName) {
   this.programName = programName;
  }

}
```

When we try to persist this domain object in the database, user defined value provided by me is not getting persist, instead Spring framework still adding its own value. I have tried @AttributeOverride but it doesn't work in my case.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 4):

I got a solution as below.

```
@PrePersist
private void setCreateByNew() {
   setCreatedBy("anonymousUser");     
}
```

Using @PrePersist I am able to override value which I am getting from common framework.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution is to set the securityContext
`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(___{AuthToken}___)`

with the username/principal you are using to auto populate audit fields before entity save and reset it after that. (for message or event processing in asynchronous fashion). This populates both `@Createdby` and `@LastUpdatedBy` from the JPA AuditAware listener.

@PrePersist will only work if we are trying to hardcode a pre-defined String `setCreatedBy("anonymousUser");` as indicated above. It does not allow us to pass in the username/name of the user as parameter to the method.

Answer (score -1):

> for : *user defined value provided by me is not getting persist, instead Spring framework still adding its own value*

you can do it with AuditorAware interface. [3.1.3 AuditorAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.7.0.DATAJPA-580-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/auditing.html)

> In case you use either @CreatedBy or @LastModifiedBy, the auditing
>   infrastructure somehow needs to become aware of the current principal.
>   To do so, we provide an AuditorAware SPI interface that you have to
>   implement to tell the infrastructure who the current user or system
>   interacting with the application is. The generic type T defines of
>   what type the properties annotated with @CreatedBy or @LastModifiedBy
>   have to be.
>
> Here’s an example implementation of the interface using Spring
>   Security’s Authentication object:
>
> Example 3.2. Implementation of AuditorAware based on Spring Security

```
class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<User> {

  public User getCurrentAuditor() {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
      return null;
    }

    return ((MyUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUser();
  }
}
```

Comment: Be aware the natural way to do this *without Spring* is to create a `RevisionEntityListener` and set the value on the revision entity instance after Envers has constructed it.  The above is essentially Spring's wrapper around that feature.

Comment: I am aware of this scenario. But all these configuration and  AuditorAware interface is implemented in common service which is used by lots of other services. And right now my current CreatedBy and Updatedby value is coming in this way only.  But I want to override this value with different value in my individual service, Is there any way I can do that.    

Thanks for your suggestion. But I am looking for more solution.